# How to check if user input is valid?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

How would I be able to check if a user's input (email address and password) are valid within a database? I need to be able to get the user's credentials from my website and validate it with my 'testlog' database. I am new to web development and I have looked everywhere, but most of the forums do not use react-bootstrap which makes it harder for me to find the answer. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

```
//////////////////////////////Navigation Bar////////////////////////////////


    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { Navbar, Nav, Form, Col, Row, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import styled from 'styled-components';

    const Styles = styled.div`
            .navbar {
                background-color: #222;
                }
            .navbar-brand, .navbar-nav .nav-link, .form-label {
                color: #C0C0C0;
            &:hover {
                color: white;
            }
        }
            .form-inline > * {
                margin:5px 3px;
        }
        `

    class NavigationBar extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super()

            this.state = {
                email: "",
                password: ""
            }
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        }

        handleSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log(this.state);
            event.target.className += " was-validated"
        }
        handleEmailChange(event)   {
            this.setState({
                email: event.target.value
            })
        }

        handlePassChange(event)   {
            this.setState({
                password: event.target.value
            })
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <Styles>
                    <Navbar expand="lg">
                        <Navbar.Brand href="/">ABC Group</Navbar.Brand>
                        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                            <Nav className="ml-auto">
                                <Form inline onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                                    <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formHorizontalEmail">
                                        <Form.Label column sm={1000} name="email" >Email:&nbsp;</Form.Label>
                                        <Col sm={15}>
                                            <Form.Control onChange={this.handleEmailChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.email} size="sm" type="email" placeholder="Enter your email" />
                                        </Col>
                                    </Form.Group>
                                    <Form.Group as={Row} controlId="formHorizontalPassword">
                                        <Form.Label column sm={1000}>Password:&nbsp;</Form.Label>
                                        <Col sm={15}>
                                            <Form.Control onChange={this.handlePassChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.password} size="sm" type="text" placeholder="Enter your password" />
                                        </Col>
                                    </Form.Group>
                                    <Button variant="primary" type="submit">Submit</Button>
                                </Form>
                            </Nav>
                        </Navbar.Collapse>
                    </Navbar>
                </Styles>
            )
        }
    }

    export default NavigationBar;


    ///////////////////////////////////Database//////////////////////////////////


    const express = require('express');
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const app = express();

    // Create a connection
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        //Server properties
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: '',
        database: 'testlog'
      });


      connection.connect(function(error) {
        if(!!error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Connected');
        }
    });

    app.get('/', function(req, resp)  {
        //about mysql
        connection.query("SELECT * FROM  sakila.actor", function(error, rows, fields) {
            if(!!error) {
                console.log(error);
            } else {
                console.log('Successful query');
            }
        });
    })

    app.listen('3003', () => {
        console.log("Server is up and listening on 3003...")
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To implement this type of behaviour logic, you first need to decide where you will record state (in this example you probably need to maintain the state of successful / unsuccessful login, and you also need to record state about the inputs (username and password)). The common options are to use react context or react-redux.

There are some trade-offs on which to choose, and I would really recommend looking at tutorials because it is a lot to cover in a short answer here. You could look, for example at [this comparison](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-react-context-can-come-to-the-rescue-if-you-dont-know-redux-5452464642ee)

Neither of the two involves react-bootstrap so don’t worry about finding examples that  include react-bootstrap. React-bootstrap is merely about the visual rendering of your components, and you have used it correctly for what it is intended to do. Managing behaviour is a separate matter.

Once you have selected an approach to manage state, you then need to call your API from `handleSubmit` (use the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) JS function) and update your state:

```js
    handleSubmit(event) {
        // get username and password from state (redux, react context or component state)
        // ... code depends on which one you choose

        // call the backend API, sending your user inputs
        // and using a promise to get the async result
        fetch('/', { method: 'POST', body: { username: username, passowrd: password } } )
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .then((json) => /* update state with the result */);

        // your original code
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(this.state);
        event.target.className += " was-validated"
    }
```

I hope this gives some pointers that will help you use react to  its fullest.

Answer (score 0):

if I'm understanding your problem correctly it should be a pretty simple to solve!

The summary of what you need to do is send a request to your backend to verify the data.

The most basic version of this would be a post request to your backend with the username and password, then a sql query to check if the password given matches the one for the username in the request.

something like:

```
app.post('/checkPass', function(req, res) {
    let username = req.body.username;
    let password = req.body.password;
    let isValid = false;
    connection.query("Select * from users_table Where username='" + username + "' and password='" + password + "'", function(error, rows, fields) {
        if(rows.length > 0) {
          //the user is valid
          isValid = true;
        } else {
          //the user isn't valid
          isValid = false;
        }
    });
    res.send(isValid);
});
```

and the request would depend on what you're using, but somehow you need to send an http request from your frontend. (A really good client is `axios` if you haven't got one yet.)

The actual body of the request in the example above would need to have the shape

```
{
    username: //username here,
    password: //password here
}
```

Also I would consider encrypting the password on both ends if you are handling real data.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah okay, I understand now. Thank you so much. This is what I neeeded!